# Request get method route handling

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 . I want to set route like

```
http://localhost:8000/website/product-search-data?term=k
```

I also tried with

```
Route::get('/website/product-search-data/*', 'websiteController@searchProductList');
public function searchProductList($term)
{
    dd($term);
 }
```

But its providing me Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. How can I handle and get parameer value ?

Comment: the query string isn't part of the path for routing, it is considered inputs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can try this instead:

```
Route::get('/website/product-search-data/{term}', 'websiteController@searchProductList');

public function searchProductList($term) {
    dd($term);
}
```